# How do I display this array correctly in html?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, arrays

I'm sending array from Php to Javascript, then I try to generate a div for each value of that array to display them in html, but instead of making a div for each independent value it stacks them all on a single one. It seems the array I'm making in php arranges all the values from my database into single string. 
How can I separate them?

[Here's how the error looks upfront](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJEVB.png)

Here's part of my  code:

Php:

```
$query= "SELECT titulo FROM notas WHERE usuario_idusuario = '".$ide."'";


//Runs the search
$resultado = $conn->query($query);



if($resultado->num_rows>0){



 while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){

  //inserts result in an array

   $contenido= array('titulo'=> $row['titulo']);

  //json_encode

   $objJson = json_encode($contenido["titulo"]);



//sends the array to javascript 

   echo "$objJson\n";  

}

}else{

  echo "Error";

}

$conn->close();

?>
```

javascript:

```
   //response receives the array 
    success: function(response){

      console.log(response);
      console.log(response.length);


      var contenidoInt = new Array();

      contenidoInt = [{


        "titulo":response



      }];



      console.log(contenidoInt);
      console.log(contenidoInt[0].titulo);


      }
```

I hope someone can help me, thanks.

Comment: `$query= "SELECT titulo FROM notas WHERE usuario_idusuario = '".$ide."'";` There's an injection vulnerability if ever there was one. What would happen if `$id` was something like `quote'delux"`? PS: Xdebug, `console.log` or even `var_dump` can tell you a lot. In this case, they can tell you what the data actually looks like

Comment: You said you wanted to put them into individual divs, but I don't see any part of your code that attempts to put them into separate divs?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem thanks! I'll look into that.

Comment: @GreeKatrina, yes I have a for that gets all the elements from the array and then appends them in the section where I need the divs to appear sort of "$(".section).append("<div>"+ contents[i].name .....+"</div>");" but maybe it was too long  for the editor.

Comment: I think you need to json decode the server response. You can do this with the JSON.Parse function. See: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp